# Mongodb LookUp Poor Performance

Tags: mongodb

```
var product = db.GetCollection<Product>("Product");
var lookup1 = new BsonDocument(
    "$lookup", 
    new BsonDocument { 
        { "from", "Variant" }, 
        { "localField", "Maincode" }, 
        { "foreignField", "Maincode" }, 
        { "as", "variants" } 
    }
);
var pipeline = new[] { lookup1};
var result = product.Aggregate<Product>(pipeline).ToList();
```

The data of collection a is very large so it takes me 30 seconds to put the data in the list.
What should I do to make a faster lookup?

Comment: Did you try to create an index for "Maincode" field?

Comment: I did crate an index for maincode in mongodb but I can't lookup.

Comment: If indexing local field didn't help that much you can use "sharded collection" or pagination for your query if you don't need all the data in one bunch.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it step by step? can you post sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that query is doing is retrieving every document from the `Product` collection, and then for each document found, perform a find query in the `Variant` collection.  If there is no index on the `Maincode` field in the `Variant` collection, it will be reading the entire collection for each document.

This means that if there are, say, 1000 total products, with 3000 total variants (3 per product, on average), this query will be reading all 1000 documents from `Product`, and if that index isn't there, it would read all 3000 documents from `Variant` 1000 times, i.e. it will be examining 3 million documents.

Some ways to possibly speed this up:

- create an index on `{Maincode:1}` in the `Variant` collection
  This will reduce the number of documents that must be read in order to complete the lookup
- change the schema
  If the variants are stored in the same document with the product, there is no need for a lookup
- filter the products prior to lookup
  Again, reducing the documents read during the lookup
- use a cursor to retrieve the documents in batches
  If you perform any necessary sorting first, and the lookup last, you can return the documents to the application in batches, which would allow the application to display or begin processing the first batch before the second batch is available.  This doen't make the query itself faster, but it can reduced the perceived wait in the application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have problem. 
Even though I use index, Lookup takes 40 seconds. I have 2000 product documents, 10000 variant documents. Datatable insert all incoming data. Before using index it was taking longer time thanks to your help i did it but this is also a very long time.